# Magento 1.9 review_save_after event not working

Tags: magento-1.9

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <d_Reviews>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </d_Reviews>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <reviews>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>d_Reviews</module>
                    <frontName>reviews</frontName>
                </args>
            </reviews>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <model>
            <d_Reviews>
                <class>d_Reviews_Model</class>
            </d_Reviews>
        </model>
        <blocks>
            <d_Reviews>
                <class>d_Reviews_Block</class>
            </d_Reviews>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <reviews>
                <class>d_Reviews_Helper</class>
            </reviews>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <review_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <d_Reviews_Model_Observer>
                        <class>reviews/observer</class>
                        <method>sendReview</method>
                    </d_Reviews_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </review_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <reviewsettings>
                                            <title>Settings</title>
                                        </reviewsettings>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

observer class

```
    class D_Reviews_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendReview(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::log("here it is");
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($object);die;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have added `sendReview` as your method name in config.xml. So you need to create a function with name `sendReview`. Please change your observer function from `sendEvent` to `sendReview` and it should work

Comment: use `D` instead of `d` in your `config.xml` for namespace

Comment: I have done the change but it still didt not work

Comment: check your module by creating test controller files and hit url,if module is working then you need to check observer area that you are using for frontend or backend.

Comment: I have created the test controller and that is working properly. I have found that magento is loading the observer from core pool not the locale pool

Comment: The issue is in the name of the observer class

Answer (score 0):

Here you add class and method to process event:

```
...
<class>reviews/observer</class>
<method>sendReview</method>
...
```

But in your config file you use name **'d_Reviews'** for model.
Try to replace `<class>reviews/observer</class>` with `<class>d_Reviews/observer</class>`

Answer (score 0):

**config.xml**

```
...
<events>
    <review_save_after>
        <observers>
            <d_Reviews_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>d_Reviews/observer</class>
                <method>sendReview</method>
            </d_Reviews_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </review_save_after>
</events>
...
```

Comment: @Manoj Thakur Please accept the answer that you find helpful